# custom post for slider

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

I am trying to create custom slider so  trying to print all ul in same li . but problem is that I am getting data in different different ul.
Here is query.

```
            <?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'slider', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<ul>';?>
    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
        <?php
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'thumbnail zoom' ) );?>
    <p><a href="#."><?php the_title();?></a></p>
    </li>
   <?php echo '</ul>';
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Here Is output

```
   <ul>    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
        <img width="1364" height="612" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner5.jpg" class="thumbnail zoom" alt="" srcset="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner5.jpg 1364w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner5-300x135.jpg 300w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner5-768x345.jpg 768w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner5-1024x459.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1364px) 100vw, 1364px" />    <p><a href="#.">slider2</a></p>
    </li>
   </ul><ul>    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
        <img width="1364" height="612" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner4.jpg" class="thumbnail zoom" alt="" srcset="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner4.jpg 1364w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner4-300x135.jpg 300w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner4-768x345.jpg 768w, http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/main-banner4-1024x459.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 1364px) 100vw, 1364px" />    <p><a href="#.">slider1</a></p>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Preblem is because inside loop you have UL

```
echo '<ul>';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
            <?php
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'thumbnail zoom' ) );?>
        <p><a href="#."><?php the_title();?></a></p>
        </li>
       <?php 
    endwhile;echo '</ul>';
```

Just make one IF statment before echo-ing UL tag

```
     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($loop-have_posts()):
  echo '<ul>';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      ?>
        <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
            <?php
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'thumbnail zoom' ) );?>
        <p><a href="#."><?php the_title();?></a></p>
        </li>
       <?php
    endwhile;  echo '</ul>';endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<ul>` out of the `while` loop:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo '<ul>';
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
    <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="6">
        <?php
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'thumbnail zoom' ) );?>
    <p><a href="#."><?php the_title();?></a></p>
    </li>
   <?php
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
echo '</ul>';
```